# Applet - Unable to write file

Tags: java, html, applet, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to write sample file from applet but is not working. Below is the code.

Applet

```
public class PasteImageApplet extends JApplet {

    Clipboard clipboard;
    Toolkit toolkit;
    JLabel lbl;

    public String getClipboardImageURL(String server) {
        lbl.setText("pasting image");

        String url = "";
        try {
            DataFlavor dataFlavor = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
            System.out.println(dataFlavor.getDefaultRepresentationClass());
            Object object = null;

            try {
                object = clipboard.getContents(null)
                        .getTransferData(dataFlavor);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Image found.");
                try
                {
                Writer output = null;
                String text = "Test Write File";
                File file = new File("write.txt");
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                output.write(text);
                output.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error writing file"+ex);
                    return "" ;
                }
                //return "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No image found.");
                return "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error."+e);
            return "";
        }

         return url;
    }

    public void init() {
        lbl = new JLabel("");
        lbl.setText("applet started");
        add(lbl);
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Clipboard image demo</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadApplet() {
                // Deferred load to display text first
                document.getElementById("applet").innerHTML = '<object id="paste-image" classid="java:PasteImageApplet.class" type="application/x-java-applet" archive="tst.jar" width="1" height="1"></object>';
            }

            function getImage() {
                obj = document.getElementById('paste-image');
                postTo = "http://localhost/PasteImageApplet/PasteImageApplet/Web/shoot.php"; // Change this to your URL

                image = obj.getClipboardImageURL(postTo);

                if (image) {
                    url = "shots/" + image;

                    document.getElementById("target").src = url;
                    document.getElementById("url").value = document.getElementById("target").src; // to get full path, hack, I know ;)
                    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "";
                }
            }
        </script>

        <body onload="loadApplet();">

            <p>
                Copy some image data to your clipboard, accept the applet (it only accesses the clipboard) and click the button :-)
                <a href="http://lassebunk.dk/2009/07/19/using-the-clipboard-to-post-images/">See a blog post about this demo</a>
            </p>

            <p>
                <div id="applet"></div>
                <input type="button" value="Paste it!" onclick="getImage();">
            </p>

            <div id="container" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" id="url" style="width: 700px;"><br />
                <iframe id="target" width="700" height="400"></iframe>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I didn't get any error as well. Please advice.

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because applets live there own sandbox, where they require special permission to perform certain operations, like read or write the disk of a client machine.  Remember, applets execute within the context of the client machine, they are guests and need to follow the house rules

Check out [What Applets can and cannot do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) for more details

Comment: I want write the file in server. The docs says applet cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and printers. How about i want to write the file in server. Same location where i saved me applet class

Comment: You've still got a (potential) problem.  You will need to be able to do a (HTTP) "post" back to the server.  This requires a connection to be established back to the server and the server to have the capacity to accept that request.  The problem here is that the Applet sand box "might" block the connection.  You'd have to try

Answer (score 1):

An applet cannot establish a `File` on the server.  That is not how servers work.  If a server accepts uploads, it must provide specific functionality to enable that and the applet must use that functionality.

As long as the functionality to accept an upload is on the same server, the applet can remain sand-boxed.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the console for applets via the (windows) taskbar, you right click the java icon(when applet is running it should appear on the lower right) and right click > open console, you can debug there, this is where the stack trace of an applet goes.