# Signed applet write file in server

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

I'm trying save file from a signed applet to server. I found a mix answer when try to google about it, some of them saying it cannot be done since applet is running in client/local machine. Some of them post sample code but its not working for me. Appreciated if some one could advice on this. Any link for references is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give details, what problem you are facing ?

Comment: I want to know whether we can write from applet to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applet - Unable to write file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779024/applet-unable-to-write-file)  The answer I would provide here, is identical to the answer I provided on that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets live there own sandbox, where they require special permission to perform certain operations, like read or write the disk of a client machine. Remember, applets execute within the context of the client machine, they are guests and need to follow the house rules. Reference - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)