# How to call java methods in a .jar file from javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I know there are many similar questions on the internet but none of them could solve my doubt. So pardon me. About my project. I have a java file or program that takes a string , encrypts it and then returns the encrypted string to me.

I want to include or keep this java file (.jar file) on the webpage or the client-side. Now I know that we can upload this java program on server side and then easily communicate with it instead of calling keeping it on client-side which most people consider a bad practice.

But my purpose of keeping this jar file on the client side is that JavaScript code for encryption can be easily seen if we inspect element, so compared to it .jar file is more secure and one cannot see underlying encryption code and also if in case the there is network loss then instead of typing the entire string again and getting it encrypted again from the server, I want to save that string in such situation, get it encrypted from the jar file on the client-side so that once network problem is solved I don't need to retype whole message again and then I can directly send the message or the string to the other end or to other user on the network.

So for this I need help regarding how can I store my .jar file on webpage or client-side and then how to call methods from the .jar file using JavaScript. I know applets are deprecated, chrome does not support java. I have also seen some examples on internet like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html but Its not working properly for me.

So I am in search of some ideal method by which I can first of all include or upload .jar file on client-side and then a method by which I can call java methods from .jar file using JavaScript. Please help... My earnest request...!

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript code for encryption can be easily seen if we inspect element

I'm assuming you mean embedded Javascript here. Because you can refer to an external JS files which are located on the web server, not the client machine.

The browser may cache your script file somewhere locally but if one were bothered enough to dig it up, he might as well decompile your jar file which is much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

- Java can easily be decompiled. A jar file on the client will not be more secure than client-side JavaScript.
- An encryption method that is compromised by looking at its code is not secure.

Comment: ok. So what do you think would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: Don't use your Java encryption method.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have many misconceptions... here are some facts for you to consider:

1. A JAR file (as either an application, WebStart or applet) running on client-side is NOT secure. If it runs on my computer, I can do anything I want. I can download the JAR file and decompile it. It's no better than JavaScript in this regard, it just takes slightly more effort and knowledge.
2. To protect data between client and server, you can simply use HTTPS and POST the data from web page to your server.
3. If client is encrypting data to you, there should be nothing to hide about the encryption process. The client generates a session key to encrypt the data, then wrap that session key by your server's public key. Then client send both encrypted data and wrapped session key to your server. Read more about Public Key Infrastructure (PKI): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure
4. By default a Java applet/WebStart is not granted access to disk. You must sign it to write data to disk, and user/security policies can still deny granting those access rights. ([Applet - Unable to write file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779024/applet-unable-to-write-file))
5. As you are aware of it, applet/WebStart is dying because of browsers rejecting plugins. There's Web Cryptography API (it's not mature, and there's no hardware support), you can try that instead. https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable information. So What would you suggest me in the end? I mean how can I be able to securely include .jar file in the client-side?

Comment: As the answers have stated, using JavaScript or Java makes no difference as both can be easily extracted. Since Java has the problem of being rejected by browsers, I don't think learning how to write a JavaApplet/WebStart would be wise - they may both become unusable soon. Instead you may want to take a look at Web Crypto API and how to use PKI (in points 3 and 5 above).

Comment: regarding point 1. Even if a person decompiles the jar file. He cannot get the original source code ?

Comment: please ignore my above comment. Is there any by which I can secure my jar file on client-side from being decompiling or in other words which can protect my jar file by either hiding it from users, or by making it inaccessible to users who try to access it..? please help.

Comment: You can give up that thought - there is absolutely no way to do that. If the code runs on client's computer, clients get to grab the memory used by the code and the code itself. You can obfuscate the code, but all it does is make it a bit harder to understand the decompiled code - the byte code is always in plain sight. I urge you to understand PKI, there should be nothing secret about the encryption process.

Comment: ok I got it. I leave the jar security issue. But just tell me how to  include/upload jar file on webpage except using applets.

Comment: If you want to implement a dying technology which you may have to replace in a few years: Java WebStart (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html). It's already clunky now, having to use workarounds on some browsers. If you want something that may last longer (but is not fully mature at the moment) you can look into Web Crypto API (https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).

Comment: While security is a good thing to care for, this does not answer the question directly. I am also in need of executing a .jar on a PC through a javascript script and I have no need for security.